# Multiplying two dataframes as matrices, preserving column and index headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df_binary and df_pim.

df_binary is shape (462,38) and df_pim is shape (36,34). They look like this:

df_binary:

```
Cust_ID   Email     Topwater  Topwater  Topwater ...  Plastic  Plastic  Plastic
12345     i@me.com  1         0         0             1        1        0
...
```

df_pim:

```
Bait Name      Technique 1     Technique 2     Technique 3   ...   Technique 33
Topwater       1               1               1                   0
...
Plastic        1               0               0                   1
```

I want the output to look like this:

df_technique:

```
Cust_ID     Email      Technique 1      Technique 2      Technique 3   ...   Technique 33
12345       i@me.com   4                1                2                   1
```

Where the 'technique' columns are the dot product of rows of df_binary and columns of df_pim.

Been struggling with this for awhile, here are three tries from what I have so far:

```
# Try 1
df_pim.iloc[:,1:].mul(df_binary)

# Try 2
df_binary.iloc[:,2:].dot(df_pim.values)

# Try 3
df_binary.iloc[:,2:].multiply(df_pim,axis='index')
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to come from the fact that your 2 extra columns Cust_ID and Email in df_binary cause your dimensions to be incompatible for matrix multiplication. Try the following:

```html
df_binary = df_binary.set_index(['Cust_id', 'Email'])
 
df_technique = df_binary.dot(df_pim.values)
  
df_techique.columns = df_pim.columns

# If you want to remove layered indicies after dot product multiplication:
df_technique.reset_index() #or set to whatever index you need.
```

You can always reset the index later if you don't want to be dealing with multi-layered indices.

Comment: Great - this didn't give me an error, which is a start, but it's outputting strings for every value along the lines of "000010001110000", rather than a single integer. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Apologies, np.dot() will output an array.  Once you've formatted df_binary to the right shape, df_binary.dot(df_pim.values) should give you what you're looking for.  I'll append my answer accordingly

Comment: I've actually previously reset the dimension size to work (hence why I use the .iloc operator) and that isn't an issue. I just need the output to not be of the form of those long strings of 1's and 0's

Comment: @Sam Kim Yes I understand, you want to keep the df integrity.  See my revised answer.  Hope that helps

Comment: I've implemented your code to use my data, but am still getting the outputs like "001110000" rather than single-digit values. Not really sure why that is. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176077/discussion-between-sam-kim-and-cvonsteg).